# Read binary header from seismic file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Tried to fetch binary headers from seismic data file. But getting 2 errors as attached below.

Code:

```
    # Open file
    with segyio.open(filename, ignore_geometry=True) as f:
    # Get all header keys:
        header_keys = segyio.binfield.keys
        print("Header Keys : ", header_keys)
        # Initialize df with trace id as index and headers as columns
        trace_headers1 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1, f.tracecount+1),columns=header_keys.keys())
        print("Trace Headers : ", trace_headers1)
        
        # Fill dataframe with all trace headers values
        for k, v in header_keys.items():
            trace_headers1[k] = f.attributes(v)[:]
    print(trace_headers.head())
    trace_headers1.to_csv('out_bin.csv')
```

ERROR:

[image]

[image]

ERROR:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you don't give the full error Traceback?

Comment: @YannisP. Shared full error. Kindly chk